# How to use AVERAGEIF function in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I am using excel to take raw data outputs and calculate multiple equations, using products of previous equations as the variables for the latter. It's all worked wonderfully except for one simple thing:

My data values are measured in duplicates, and value-pairs averaged in the earliest step. In the case that certain duplicates are inconsistent, I would like the average function to disqualify both so that they are not sent down the chain of equations. My cut-off for consistancy is 20 percent difference; that is,

| (value 1 - value 2) / ((value 1 + value 2)/2) | x 100%
where |  | signifies absolute value.

Anything less than 20% is considered good.

Comment: What is your question?  How your data looks like?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. It seems like part of your post is missing. This is a Q&A community where specific questions are asked after you have attempted something and get stuck. Please add details of what you have tried so far, including scripts, code or formulas, and we will try to help. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Answer (score 0):

Place your data pairs in columns **A** and **B**.  In **C1** enter:

```
=ABS(A1-B1)/((A1+B1)/2)
```

and copy down:

[image]

Now to delete the "bad" data, run this short macro:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").Value
    For i = N To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(i, "C").Value > 0.2 Then Cells(i, "C").EntireRow.Delete
    Next i
End Sub
```

With the result:

[image]

Continue to process only the remaining **A** & **B** data.